# Elasticsearch conditional scoring in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic Search and I wanted to ask how can I boost certain results from a query based on some conditional. Specifically, the items in Elastic Search are of the following format:

```
"name":"item1",
"desc":"desc1",
"brand":"brandname"
```

I want to make the score of certain items (those with `"brand" = "nike"`) have lower score than the other brands. Is there a way to do that with the QueryBuilders classes that java has for elastic search?

Answer (score 0):

[Boosting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.8/query-dsl-boosting-query.html#query-dsl-boosting-query) query might be able to solve the problem. Alternatively, you can also use [function_score queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) for more flexibility.

Example with boosting query.

(1) Index few documents

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/idx/doc/1 -d '{"content": "foo"}' --header "Content-type:application/json" 
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/idx/doc/2 -d '{"content": "bar"}' --header "Content-type:application/json" 
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/idx/doc/3 -d '{"content": "foo fred bar"}' --header "Content-type:application/json"
```

(2) Query with a negative boost for `bar` to reduce score for `bar`

```
 curl -XPOST localhost:9200/idx/_search?pretty -d '{
  "query": {
    "boosting": {
      "positive": {
        "match": {
          "content": "foo bar fred"
        }
      },
      "negative": {
        "match": {
          "content": "bar"
        }
      } , "negative_boost": 0.001
    }
  }
}' --header "Content-type:application/json" 


{
  "took" : 59,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.5619609,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "idx",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.5619609,
        "_source" : {
          "content" : "foo"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "idx",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 0.0014472058,
        "_source" : {
          "content" : "foo fred bar"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "idx",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 5.619609E-4,
        "_source" : {
          "content" : "bar"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To boost a certain value of a certain field (or vice versa), you can use a `Function score query`.
[Check the official document Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html).

Let me show you an example :

```js
    POST /goods/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "name": "shoes"
            }
          },
          "functions": [
            {
              "filter": {
                "term": {
                  "maker": "nike"
                }
              },
              "weight": 0
            }
          ],
          "boost_mode": "multiply"
        }
      },
      "sort": [
        {
          "_score": {
            "order": "desc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

This query refers that "I'm looking for documents which match a keyword `shoes` in a `name` field and sort in reverse order of `_score`. If documents have a term `nike` in a `maker` field, however, I hope that the score is 0(cause multiplying any number by 0 equals 0)."

In Java code,

```java
    String indexName = "goods"
    String nameField = "name";
    String makerField = "maker";

    String keyword = "shoes";
    String unnecessaryMaker = "nike";
    
    MatchQueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = new MatchQueryBuilder(nameField, keyword);
    FilterFunctionBuilder[] filterFunctions = {
        new FunctionScoreQueryBuilder.FilterFunctionBuilder(
            QueryBuilders.termQuery(makerField, unnecessaryMaker),
            ScoreFunctionBuilders.weightFactorFunction(0)
        )
    };
            
    FunctionScoreQueryBuilder functionScoreQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(matchQueryBuilder, filterFunctions);
    functionScoreQueryBuilder.boostMode(CombineFunction.MULTIPLY);

    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    searchSourceBuilder.query(functionScoreQueryBuilder);
        
    SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest();
    request.indices(indexName);
    request.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

There are several `boost_mode` such as multiply(default), replace, sum, avg, max, min.
So you can apply this code to your needs.

Hope this is what you were looking for.